# Create Bootable windows 7 ISO from Windows 7 backup files

Tags: windows, windows-7, backup, iso-image

I have a copy of windows 7 backup files which were done a couple of years back.
What I want to do now is to make a bootable iso image of these backup files and install this image into some other PC.

How can I do that?

Here is a snapshot of my windows backup files:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Windows Backup files are not designed to become bootable.

Comment: *If* you could restore those backup files to your Windows 7 PC, overwriting your current work, you could make a **disk image** that could be restored on a similar PC.

Comment: i think better would be to try restoring them on a win 7 vm

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that backup was done with Clonezilla. You need to prepare and boot LiveCD/USB with Clonezilla. The  select the location of the backup files (smb/external drive/etc.) and restore on new PC/VM.
Here is detailed guide - https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/02_Restore_disk_image